# Переключатель песен

Tags: jquery, html5

Доброго времени суток! Такая вот проблемка: хочу реализовать переключение песен плеера html5 путем изменения атрибута `src` с помощью jQuery. Названия песен имеют вид 1.mp3, 2.mp3 ... n.mp3

Вот html код:

```
<audio controls style="width:400px; float: right;">
     <source class="mp" src="music/1.mp3" type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
</audio>
```

Вот код jQuery:

```
$('.next').click(function()  //next класс кнопки
{
    $('.mp').attr('src','music/'+i+'.mp3'); //скорее всего ошибка здесь
    i++; //следующая песня, i - глобальная
});
```

Вопрос нубский до ужаса, но я не знаю)

Comment: @denisKlimenko, А что у вас в этом коде не работает? Не экспериментировал, но должно всё пахать.

Comment: уже все работает))

Answer (score 2):

можно писать просто

```
'music/' + i++ + '.mp3'
```

но я бы хранил список песен в массиве или хэше

Comment: то есть ошибка была в том, что я написал слитно? :D
Насчет массива идейка хорошая, спасибо)